# JOptionPane text showing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

Okay so the `JOptionPane` text is showing in the `JFrame` window and not even my CS professor can figure out why. It is a program to simply draw 3 lines, but it has shown the `JOptionPane` text in the JFrame window no matter which compiler that I use. Heres my code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Lab5_1 extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        String ia = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String ja = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end y point of the line");
        int jx = Integer.parseInt(ja);
        int jy = Integer.parseInt(jab);
        int ix = Integer.parseInt(ia);
        int iy = Integer.parseInt(iab);

        String iac = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iabc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String jac = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jabc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end y point of the line");
        int jxb = Integer.parseInt(jac);  
        int jyb = Integer.parseInt(jabc);
        int ixb = Integer.parseInt(iac);
        int iyb = Integer.parseInt(iabc);

        String iad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iabd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String jad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jabd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the end y point of the line");
        int jxc = Integer.parseInt(jad);
        int jyc = Integer.parseInt(jabd);
        int ixc = Integer.parseInt(iad);
        int iyc = Integer.parseInt(iabd);

        g.drawLine(ix,iy,jx,jy);
        g.drawLine(ixb,iyb,jxb,jyb);
        g.drawLine(ixc,iyc,jxc,jyc);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Lab5_1 panel = new Lab5_1(); 
        JFrame application = new JFrame(); 

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        application.add( panel ); 
        application.setSize( 500, 290 ); 
        application.setVisible( true ); 
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images as external links. Links may break in the future. Stackoverflow supports adding images ;)

Comment: Dont have enough "reputation points" to do that

Comment: PaintComponent is called when ever your component need to be painted, so each time, your JOptionPane's are been shown, each and every time ...

Comment: `paintComponent` is used for painting and should not be used for anything else. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how paint works. Painting can occur for any reason at any time, meaning your paint methods will be called repeatedly and possibly within in quick succession, they should also return as fast as possible in order to keep the UI responsive

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `JOptionPane`s out of the `paintComponent` method. The problem went away immediately. It has to do something with overriding that component. My bet would be the fact that you call `super()` in that override, but I haven't tested that hypothesis myself. The problem, whatever its cause, goes away when you move your `JOptionPane`s outside `paintComponent`.

Also, I feel it would be much easier on the user to tell the use to input coordinates, then parsing those coordinates into the `jx`, `jy`, etc. variables. Simpler and only three panes instead of six.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lab5_1 extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static int jx;
    private static int jy;
    private static int ix;
    private static int iy;
    private static int jxb;
    private static int jyb;
    private static int ixb;
    private static int iyb;
    private static int jxc;
    private static int jyc;
    private static int ixc;
    private static int iyc;

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(ix, iy, jx, jy);
        g.drawLine(ixb, iyb, jxb, jyb);
        g.drawLine(ixc, iyc, jxc, jyc);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTesting panel = new SwingTesting();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        String ia = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String ja = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end y point of the line");
        jx = Integer.parseInt(ja);
        jy = Integer.parseInt(jab);
        ix = Integer.parseInt(ia);
        iy = Integer.parseInt(iab);

        String iac = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iabc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String jac = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jabc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end y point of the line");
        jxb = Integer.parseInt(jac);
        jyb = Integer.parseInt(jabc);
        ixb = Integer.parseInt(iac);
        iyb = Integer.parseInt(iabc);

        String iad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning  x point of the line");
        String iabd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the beginning y point of the line");
        String jad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end  x point of the line");
        String jabd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the end y point of the line");
        jxc = Integer.parseInt(jad);
        jyc = Integer.parseInt(jabd);
        ixc = Integer.parseInt(iad);
        iyc = Integer.parseInt(iabd);

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(500, 290);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `paintComponent` is used for painting and should not be used for anything else. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how paint works. You hypothesis is generally wrong. The next problem is the reliance on `static` is generally a bad idea and a sign of a poor design

Comment: Good, don't use `static`, the OP didn't, lets not introduce more bad habits

Comment: So exactly how are we going to reference `int` fields from a static context in the main method? Compile error occurs otherwise.

Comment: Switch to a non-static context